# Adaboost vs Gradient Boosting Difference

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, adaboost

Both Adaboost algorithm and Gradient Boosting (with exponential loss function) try to minimize the exponential loss function.

From Elements of Statistical Learning p.344: "Hence
we conclude that AdaBoost.M1 minimizes the exponential loss criterion
(10.8) via a forward-stagewise additive modeling approach".

If I follow the procedure in "GREEDY FUNCTION APPROXIMATION: A GRADIENT BOOSTING MACHINE" with loss function the exponential loss I end up with different predictions.

My question is why these two differ since both have the objective to minimize the exponential loss and which is preferable and why?

Comment: Neither is really preferable.  I would say gradient boosting with the log-loss function is the better approach in 2018.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why these two end up with different results?